# Angular2 - loading the same router with other parameter does not load new view

Tags: angular, router, reloading

I'm at page /offers/(offerID)
At the page I have the offer details and 5 last added other offers.

current page - /offers/(offerID)

at the page there is a code

```
<a [routerLink]="['/offers/', offer.id]>other offer</a>
```

when I click on the link, page url DOES CHANGE but view of the router DOES NOT. I have to refresh page to get the same router but with loaded details of the new offer.

Is there a solution? Thanks

Comment: Could you add plunkr?

Comment: isolating your issue in a plunker: https://plnkr.co/   will maximize your chances of getting help; if SO users can experience your problem they will help you find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, I did it. I just run a function to search the offer with new ID so there is no need to reload the router.